# what causes Exhausted heap space error in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

> E/DartVM  (17813): Exhausted heap space, trying to allocate 67108880
> bytes. E/flutter (17813):
> [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled
> Exception: Out of Memory E/flutter (17813): #0      new _List.filled
> (dart:core-patch/array.dart:97:20) E/flutter (17813): #1
> _TimerHeap._resize (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:68:9) E/flutter (17813): #2      _TimerHeap.add
> (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:30:7) E/flutter (17813): #3
> _Timer._enqueue (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:261:13) E/flutter (17813): #4      Timer._createTimer
> (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:17:19) E/flutter (17813): #5
> new Future.delayed (dart:async/future.dart:422:9) E/flutter (17813):
> #6      _ReelsScreenState.build.. (package:movies/Views/reels_screen.dart:348:36)

Am building an app similar to Instagram reels and am using better player package, now the problem am facing is the memory issue "Exhausted heap", so how can i increase the heap space?